# Add auto focus on Email Textbox while log in in using Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, design

Add auto focus on email textbox after clicking on "Log in using Stack Exchange".
I'm presenting this change from usability perspective. So user can directly enter his credential with less mouse clicks.

Please check below image for reference.

[image: Stack Exchange log in screen]